# How to generate a Thumbnail from video path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I list all video files from internal storage now I want to show a thumbnail of every file in the leading property

i ask a question in flutter and hope will get a better response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

For Others. Use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin as thumbnail. It's very effients comapare to those libraries and also works for ios.Just create statefullWidget as like item(if you want to show in list use that widget as item). See below example.

```
class _VideoItemState extends State<VideoItem> {
VideoPlayerController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.video.file.path)
  ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});  //when your thumbnail will show.
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
_controller.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListTile(
  leading: _controller.value.initialized
      ? Container(
          width: 100.0,
          height: 56.0,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        )
      : CircularProgressIndicator(),
  title: Text(widget.video.file.path.split('/').last),
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            VideoPlayerPage(videoUrl: widget.video.file.path),
      ),
    );
  },
);
 }
}
```